# How to make transform: scale work with transition and animation on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I am trying to make hover scale work smoothly with animation scale. Hover works with #test but with .rotate I can't get it to work correctly. Also, why the hover scale doesn't work when the animation-fill-mode is forwards instead of none?

https://codepen.io/yoholil/pen/qBLbYYm

```js
let flag = false;
let test = document.querySelector("#test")


test.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(1);
  flag && test.classList.add("rotate");
  !flag && test.classList.remove("rotate");
  flag = !flag;
});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 200px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  animation: rotateRight 0.3s ease-in-out none;
}

#test:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

#test.rotate {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  animation: rotateLeft 0.3s ease-in-out none;
}

@keyframes rotateRight {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

@keyframes rotateLeft {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="test" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/768px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the new `scale` property along with the transform one.

Your code can be simplified like below

```js
let test = document.querySelector("#test")

test.addEventListener("click", function() {
  test.classList.toggle("rotate");
});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 200px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#test:hover {
  scale: 1.2;
}

#test.rotate {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<img id="test" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/768px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the initial flip animation, then consider using a CSS variable that carries the scaling multiplier so that it works within the `animation`:

```js
let flag = false;
let test = document.querySelector("#test")


test.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(1);
  flag && test.classList.add("rotate");
  !flag && test.classList.remove("rotate");
  flag = !flag;
});
```

```css
#test {
  transform: scale(var(--multiplier));
  width: 200px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  animation: rotateRight 0.3s ease-in-out none;
  --multiplier: 1;
}

#test:hover {
  --multiplier: 1.2;
}

#test.rotate {
  transform: scale(calc(-1 * var(--multiplier)), var(--multiplier));
  animation: rotateLeft 0.3s ease-in-out none;
}

@keyframes rotateRight {
  0% {
    transform: scale(calc(-1 * var(--multiplier)), var(--multiplier));
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(var(--multiplier));
  }
}

@keyframes rotateLeft {
  0% {
    transform: scale(var(--multiplier));
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(calc(-1 * var(--multiplier)), var(--multiplier));
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="test" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/768px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png" />
```

Otherwise, if you don't need the initial flip animation, consider removing the use of any `animation` altogether:

```js
let flag = false;
let test = document.querySelector("#test")


test.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(1);
  flag && test.classList.add("rotate");
  !flag && test.classList.remove("rotate");
  flag = !flag;
});
```

```css
#test {
  transform: scale(var(--multiplier));
  width: 200px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  --multiplier: 1;
}

#test:hover {
  --multiplier: 1.2;
}

#test.rotate {
  transform: scale(calc(-1 * var(--multiplier)), var(--multiplier));
}
```

```html
<img id="test" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/768px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png" />
```

---

Additionally, the hover scale doesn't work when the `animation-fill-mode` is `forwards` instead of `none` because the `transform` property value in the `@keyframes` would take precedence over any of properties defined in the CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a wrapper and apply `:hover` to it:

```js
test.addEventListener('click', () => test.classList.toggle('rotate'));
```

```css
#test {
  width: 200px;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

#test:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

#test img{
  animation: rotateRight .3s ease-in-out both;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#test.rotate img{
  animation: rotateLeft .3s ease-in-out both;
}

@keyframes rotateRight {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

@keyframes rotateLeft {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/768px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png">
</div>
```